# Identifying 紫砂壶 product description (Calligraphy)

Tags: character-identification, calligraphy

I was gifted a 紫砂壶, and although I can read standard characters, I'm having a hard time piecing together this product description. Here is what I have so far, and I'm having to guess a lot:

```
五四三二一　
　　　　　　　
　大紫此作　一
二方砂壶品　二
？二？？說　三
？？？用書　四
茶？？原　　五
？堪？曠　　六
　及造？　　七
　其型？　　八
　藏古？　　九
　？樸？　　十
```

As you can see, I'm not very good at reading calligraphy.

Also, I am confused at why there would be a simplified version of 优 at the bottom if the rest is traditional?

[image: teapot description]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

作品證書

此杯採用原礦優質

紫砂原料造型古樸

大方工藝精湛極具藏價

工藝美術師

> 作品證書: (Work certificate:)
>
> 此杯採用原礦優質紫砂原料，造型古樸大方。(This cup is made of high-quality raw materials of purple sand from the original ore, the style is classically simple and elegant.)
>
> 工藝精湛，極具藏價。(Superb craftsmanship, extremely worthy of collecting.)
>
> ~ 工藝美術師 (from: The craftsman)

藏價 is short for 收藏價值

*The text has no punctuation mark and change column in the wrong places. Also mixing traditional and simplified characters (some in variant form) together. No wonder you can't get what it said.*

Simplified Chinese:

> 作品证书:
>
> 此杯采用原矿优质紫砂原料，造型古朴大方。
>
> 工艺精湛，极具藏价。
>
> ~ 工艺美术师

Comment: Wow, amazingly fast and coherent reply! Thank you. Do you know why they simplified some characters but not others? I am confused why for example they used 及其 instead of 極具, or 优质 instead of 優質. I don't know anything about calligraphy, so maybe there is an obvious reason.

Comment: Yes, I am annoyed by the writer mixing traditional and simplified characters together too.

Comment: May be the writer though using traditional  Chinese make the product look more classical, but didn't know how to write some of them.